# Writing in text files in python

Tags: python

I am using the code...

```
C1 = open("Class 1.txt", "w")
C1.write("\n\nName: %s" % S_N)
C1.write("\nScore: %s" % correct)
C1.close()
```

To write in a text file in python, but every time I run the code it re-sets what was in the text file before. For example this code would enter someone's name and the score that they got in a quiz. When I run the program the first time it works perfectly fine and stores the name and score in a text file which I can see later. But when I run the code for the second time the name and score of the first person is deleted and replaced with the score of the second person.

Ys there anyway to change this???

Comment: Try using the **append** mode instaed of **write** mode to open a file as : `C1 = open("Class 1.txt", "a")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a file `w` mode overwrites the file. What you want to use is `a`, which appends to the file:

```
C1 = open("Class 1.txt", 'a')
C1.write("\n\nName: %s" % S_N)
C1.write("\nScore: %s" % correct)
C1.close()
```

Also consider using this approach whenever reading and writing to files:

```
with open("Class 1.txt", 'a') as C1:
    C1.write("\n\nName: %s" % S_N)
    C1.write("\nScore: %s" % correct)
```

Helps if you ever forget to `close` or hit uncaught exceptions.